# How to access dictionary values using a variable: Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I access a dictionary value using a for loop and an array?

For example:
I have a dictionary:

```
var dict = {
    machine_41: {
        temp: "14",
        humidity: "89",
        time: Wed Oct 31 2018 12: 27: 16 GMT - 0500(Central Daylight Time)
    },
    machine_42: {
        temp: "20",
        humidity: "13",
        time: Wed Oct 31 2018 12: 27: 41 GMT - 0500(Central Daylight Time)
    },
    machine_43: {
        temp: "34",
        humidity: "36",
        time: Wed Oct 31 2018 1 GMT - 0500(Central Daylight Time)
    }
```

I know I can access values by using `console.log(dict.machine_41.temp)`
However, how can I do this with a for loop, and an array?

I have tried:

```
      let activeMachines = [41,43,45];
      for(let i = 0; i < activeMachines.length; i++){
          let machine = ('machine_'+ activeMachines[i]);
          console.log(htmldata.machine.temp);
       }
```

I was hoping it would substitute `machine` for `machine_41`, and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do the following:

```js
var dict = {
    machine_41: {
        temp: "14",
        humidity: "89",
        time: 'Wed Oct 31 2018 12: 27: 16 GMT - 0500(Central Daylight Time)'
    },
    machine_42: {
        temp: "20",
        humidity: "13",
        time: 'Wed Oct 31 2018 12: 27: 41 GMT - 0500(Central Daylight Time)'
    },
    machine_43: {
        temp: "34",
        humidity: "36",
        time: 'Wed Oct 31 2018 1 GMT - 0500(Central Daylight Time)'
    }
}

let activeMachines = [41,43,45];

for(const machineNumber of activeMachines) {

    let machineKey = `machine_${ machineNumber }`
    let machine = dict[ machineKey ]
    
    if(machine) {
      console.log(`tempurature for machine ${ machineNumber}: ${ machine.temp }`);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a common way and should be the accepted answer. But square bracket notation is an antipattern as it might introduce a security issue (leading to remote code execution).
Using the eslint-plugin `security/recommended` this would lead to an error here.

https://web.archive.org/web/20150430062816/https://blog.liftsecurity.io/2015/01/15/the-dangers-of-square-bracket-notation

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to gather the keys of an object, with that array you can loop and access the objects.

```js
var dict = {  machine_41: {    temp: "14",    humidity: "89",    time: "Wed Oct 31 2018 12: 27: 16 GMT - 0500(Central Daylight Time)"  },  machine_42: {    temp: "20",    humidity: "13",    time: "Wed Oct 31 2018 12: 27: 41 GMT - 0500(Central Daylight Time)"  },  machine_43: {    temp: "34",    humidity: "36",    time: "Wed Oct 31 2018 1 GMT - 0500(Central Daylight Time)"  }};

Object.keys(dict).forEach(k => {
  console.log(k, ':', dict[k].temp);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

*Or, you can use a simple [`for-loop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement) along with the operator [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in)*

```js
var dict = {  machine_41: {    temp: "14",    humidity: "89",    time: "Wed Oct 31 2018 12: 27: 16 GMT - 0500(Central Daylight Time)"  },  machine_42: {    temp: "20",    humidity: "13",    time: "Wed Oct 31 2018 12: 27: 41 GMT - 0500(Central Daylight Time)"  },  machine_43: {    temp: "34",    humidity: "36",    time: "Wed Oct 31 2018 1 GMT - 0500(Central Daylight Time)"  }};

for (let key in dict) {
  console.log(key, ':', dict[key].temp);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

*If you want to use an array of numbers related to machines, you can use the function [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)*

```js
var dict = {  machine_41: {    temp: "14",    humidity: "89",    time: "Wed Oct 31 2018 12: 27: 16 GMT - 0500(Central Daylight Time)"  },  machine_42: {    temp: "20",    humidity: "13",    time: "Wed Oct 31 2018 12: 27: 41 GMT - 0500(Central Daylight Time)"  },  machine_43: {    temp: "34",    humidity: "36",    time: "Wed Oct 31 2018 1 GMT - 0500(Central Daylight Time)"  }},
    activeMachines = [41,43,45];

activeMachines.forEach(m => console.log(`machine_${m}`, ':', (dict[`machine_${m}`] || {temp: 'Temperature not found.'}).temp));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array like notation. Example:

```
htmldata[machine].temp
```

You can even use two variables:

```
htmldata[machine][anotherVariable]
```

A working [example](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln4swy7b/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Use dict[machime] to refer to the property you want

```
var dict = {
machine_41: {temp: "14", humidity: "89", time: "Wed Oct   31 2018 12:27:16 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)"},
machine_42: {temp: "20", humidity: "13", time: "Wed Oct    31 2018 12:27:41 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)"},
machine_43: {temp: "34", humidity: "36", time: "Wed Oct 31 2018 1 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)"}};
let activeMachines = [41,43,45];
      for(let i = 0; i < activeMachines.length; i++){
          let machine = ('machine_'+ activeMachines[i]);
          console.log(dict[machine]);
       }
```